# onChange to check all property of object exist and is not undefined or empty string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

This is a very common usage where you have to check whether all fields are filled. I use react `onChange` and apply `e.target.name` as key to my object.

like I do `console.log(this.state.user);` I will get

```
user : {
    name:"something",
    age:1
}
```

but how to check if everything is not empty or null? I check manually like `user.name != undefined` but my key is more than 10. Is there any better lodash method to do this?

I set state like this

```
const user = this.state.user;
user[field] = event.target.value;

this.setState({
    user
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the values of your object and use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=control) method.

```
const allExist = Object.values(this.state.user)
  .reduce(function(accumulator, current){
   return accumulator && !!current
  }, true);
```

```js
const user = {
  name:"something",
  age:1
}

const allExist = Object.keys(user)
  .reduce(function(accumulator, current){
   return accumulator && !!current
  }, true);
  
console.log(allExist);
```

Comment: is the true, the second param of reduce needed?

Comment: It's the initial value. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. I use that because it makes sure I always get a bool value as output, even there is one property in the object.

Comment: You get error or wrong result? can I see your full `user` object?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.keys` method - loop the resulting array and check that each key has a valid value:

```js
const user = {
  name: "Tom",
  age: 28,
  address: null,
  occupation: "Programmer",
  interest: "JavaScript",
  dob: undefined
}

const keys = Object.keys(user);
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  if (user[keys[i]] == null) {
    console.log(`${keys[i]} needs a value`);
  }
}
```